# In java servlets, are ServletContext attributes available to views automatically?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If I set an attribute in my ServletContext object, does a view automatically have access to it? I'm trying to figure out how this JSP page is accessing a variable which is set in the ServletContextListener and nowhere else, so the only conclusion I can come up with is it must be available directly from the context object. If this is true, then what's the difference between setting a value in the ServletContext, and setting one in the request. Is it sort of like the difference between the session and the request?

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452 and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** You will have the access to it in JSP.

> The Tomcat will convert/Generate servlets for all JSPs.

So you have almost same access what you have for Java Servlets in JSP too.
That means both of them will have access to **servletConfig**.

All jsp generated servlets will extend [HttpJspBase](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/runtime/HttpJspBase.html) which intern extends GenericServlet and GenericServlet has the ServletConfig property. Check this [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html).

---

**ServletContext attributes** are attributes at the container[tomcat] level, as per the docs

```
/**
 *
 * Defines a set of methods that a servlet uses to communicate with its
 * servlet container, for example, to get the MIME type of a file, dispatch
 * requests, or write to a log file.
 *
 * <p>There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine.  (A
 * "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a
 * specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as <code>/catalog</code>
 * and possibly installed via a <code>.war</code> file.)
 *
```

So there will be only one context per application and what ever the attributes you set will be accessible to all servlets, irrespective of any particular session or request.

Where as **Session attributes** are attributes set at the session level, there can be many sessions going on in the container and it is maintained by both the client[usually browser] and the container using `session-id` mechanism. You will have the access to the attributes set in a session, till the session ends.

Finally **Request attributes** lifetime is till you serve that request. Once your container sends back the result, the attributes you set will be destroyed.

Check the below javaDoc of ServletRequest.removeAttribute(...)

```
 /**
 * Removes an attribute from this request. This method is not generally
 * needed as attributes only persist as long as the request is being
 * handled.
 */
public void removeAttribute(String name);
```